# calling DROP USER from a stored proc, how to expand the input argument

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to set up a stored proc that (in part) drops a user. I've tried several versions of DROP USER that "expand" the argument and I can't find one that works. Can someone help?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `dropuser`( IN inUser varchar(255) )
BEGIN
  #DROP USER concat(inUser,"@localhost");
  #DROP USER inUser "@localhost";
  #DROP USER "inUser@localhost";
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL dropuser("asdf");
```

All three of them fail in the same way:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(inUser,"@localhost");
```

Obviously I'm getting the expansion wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists dropuser //
create procedure dropuser( in inUser varchar(255) )
begin
  set @str = concat('drop user ', "'",inUser,"'@","'localhost'");
  prepare stmt from @str;
  -- select @str;  
  execute stmt;
  deallocate prepare stmt;
end//
delimiter ;

call dropuser('pippo');
```

Comment: perfect! I can also use `GRANT.. IDENTIFIED BY` to keep from needing to do this.